# Return value of SQLCMD RESTORE in cmd batch

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

I am building a cmd script to restore a SQL Server database, and I need to know if the RESTORE worked correctly, in order to perform other tasks.
My code:

```
sqlcmd -S %DATABASE_SERVER% -U user-P password-Q "RESTORE DATABASE %Database% FROM DISK='I:\bakup.bak'"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup command doesn't return an error code. Moreover, backup error can be found in error log only, not in any of the system catalogs.

There is a table `msdb.dbo.backupset` with information on successful backups, though, and it can be used to deduce whether the backup errored or not.

Make a note of the current time prior to taking the backup, and after the backup finishes use a query like this to retireve the time of the last successful backup:

```
select max(backup_start_date)
from msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name = 'database_name'
```

If the time returned is less than the one you recorded then there were errors.